# Jackson @JsonIgnore dont work for collections like set,map,list via MixIn annotations

Tags: json, collections, annotations, set, jackson

I tried to create an interface that will used as mix-in annotations for jackson.

the annotation @JsonIgnore works for types like String,int,CustomObject
but it doesnt work for Collections like Set, List, Map
I still get the Collection as part of my JSON output.

I put the @JsonIgnore only on the getter that return the Collection for example:

```
@JsonIgnore
Set<CustomObject> getCustomObjects();
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had JAXB annotations on the members.
it seems that they override the getter mixin annotations.
this was wrong because all annotations should be on the getter.

I also change:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
```

in the class because FIELD is wrong.